# I cant get nginx infront of kestrel to serve gzip content

Tags: nginx

I have some services running on dotnet core and kestrel, with nginx infront.

But for some reason it wont servce gzip-content, even though I configured to do so.

My generated nginx config looks like the following:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    keepalive_timeout          65;
    gzip                       on;
    gzip_http_version  1.1;
    gzip_comp_level    5;
    gzip_min_length    1000;
    gzip_proxied       any;
    gzip_vary          on;
    gzip_types
        text/css
        text/*
        text/javascript
        message/*
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/atom+xml
        application/xaml+xml;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    upstream GatewayService {
        server 10.0.0.6:65053 backup;
        server 10.0.0.5:59957 backup;
        server 10.0.0.4:49210 ;
    }
    upstream EarthML_IdentityService {
        server 10.0.0.6:64872 backup;
        server 10.0.0.5:59896 backup;
        server 10.0.0.4:49211 ;
    }
    upstream EarthML_Mapify_Portal {
        server 10.0.0.6:54063 backup;
        server 10.0.0.4:49204 ;
        server 10.0.0.5:65360 backup;
    }
    upstream EarthMLFront {
        server 10.0.0.6:65295 backup;
        server 10.0.0.5:60387 backup;
        server 10.0.0.4:49199 ;
    }
    upstream S-Innovations_StorageServiceHost {
        server 10.0.0.6:53041 backup;
        server 10.0.0.4:49195 ;
        server 10.0.0.5:64536 backup;
    }
    server {
        listen       8498;
        listen       8500 ssl;
        server_name  www.earthml.com;

        ssl_certificate D:\\SvcFab\_App\S-Innovations.ServiceFabric.GatewayApplicationType_App15\work/letsencrypt/www.earthml.com.fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key D:\\SvcFab\_App\S-Innovations.ServiceFabric.GatewayApplicationType_App15\work/letsencrypt/www.earthml.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        location /manage/ {
            proxy_pass http://GatewayService/;
            server_name_in_redirect on;
            port_in_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host                     $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server     $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path       $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-ServiceFabric-Key    "S-Innovations.ServiceFabric.GatewayApplication/GatewayService/1.0.0.20170415.02";
            proxy_connect_timeout                   3s;
            proxy_http_version                      1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-PathBase   /manage/;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
        location /identity/ {
            proxy_pass http://EarthML_IdentityService/;
            server_name_in_redirect on;
            port_in_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host                     $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server     $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path       $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-ServiceFabric-Key    "EarthML.IdentityServerApp/EarthML.IdentityService/1.0.0.20170413.02";
            proxy_connect_timeout                   3s;
            proxy_http_version                      1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-PathBase   /identity/;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://EarthMLFront/;
            server_name_in_redirect on;
            port_in_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host                     $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server     $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path       $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-ServiceFabric-Key    "EarthML.WebFrontApplication/EarthMLFront/1.0.0.20170413.01";
            proxy_connect_timeout                   3s;
            proxy_http_version                      1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-PathBase   /;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed application/javascript in the list of types to do gzip on.